# Rename command removes first character from file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm new to batch and I am trying to rename multiple files to the same name but with a number at the front (example Hello --> 1 Hello) However instead of "1 Hello" I get "1 llo"

So far this is the command I'm using

```
    rename "C:\Users\Eef\Desktop\New folder\1\*.txt" "1 *.txt"
```

as stated above when run on something like "hello" it returns "1 llo"

If i instead use,

```
    rename "C:\Users\Eef\Desktop\New folder\1\*.txt" "1*.txt"
```

It just replaces the first letter with one ("hello --> "1ello"
I would prefer to keep one line if possible. I just can't find any information about how to do this at all. Can someone show me how this might be possible?

Comment: The word you should be including in your search is "substring".

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ren "%a" "1 %a"`

Comment: …with the `%`-signs doubled up in a batch file…